# Buttons invisibles on react native

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I want to display the 2 buttons in a row above the input field

im testing this on a android device and both buttons are invisibles im testing this on expo and a physical device i dont see any errors on the terminal or messages

```
import React from 'react';
import {View, Text, StyleSheet, TextInput, Button} from 'react-native';

const StartGameScreen = props => {
    return(
        <View style={styles.screen}>
            <Text style={styles.title}>Start a new game!</Text>
            <View style={styles.inputContainer}>
                <Text>Select a number</Text>
                <TextInput/>
                <View style={styles.buttonContainer}>
                <Button title="Reset" onPress={() => {}} />
                <Button title="confirm" onPress={() => {}} />
                </View>
            </View>
        </View>
    );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    screen:{
        flex:1,
        padding: 10,
        alignItems:'center',
        justifyContent: 'flex-start',
    },
    title:{
        fontSize: 20,
        marginVertical: 10, 
    },
    inputContainer:{
        width: 300,
        maxWidth: '80%',
        alignItems: 'center'
    },
    buttonContainer:{
        flexDirection:'row',
        width:'100%',
        justifyContent: 'space-between',
        paddingHorizontal: 15
    }
});

export default StartGameScreen;
```

Comment: I'm testing online and on my device and working, the buttons is above input: https://snack.expo.io/r1g8k6EOr

Comment: thanks but i test with react-native init and i see only a trasnparent button with white text, if i use:  backgroundColor: '#DDDDDD', on the style, nothing change

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I checked your code and it works perfectly :

I generated my project with React Native CLI

```
 react-native init AwesomeProject
```

Preferably use the React Native CLI instead of Expo

If it didn't work, use Reac Native UI libs who looks like "bootstrap" for Buttons or others components :

- [NativeBase](https://docs.nativebase.io/docs/GetStarted.html)

[image: Exemple]

Comment: ok thanks but i create now the app with  react-native init AwesomeProject
 and now i see the text of the button with white text and no color of the button

Comment: You can pass props color to your button to change the background color of this one <Button color='red' /> if it's doesent work try to use ReactNative UI libs like NativeBase for exemple https://docs.nativebase.io/docs/GetStarted.html